# Prove using dot product that the angle bisectors of two adjacent angles are perpendicular

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I am asked the following problem:

> Prove using scalar product that the angle bisectors of two adjacent angles are perpendicular.

I am not sure if the following solution satisfies the problem:

[image]

$$
(\overrightarrow{u} + \overrightarrow{v} ) \cdot (\overrightarrow{u} - \overrightarrow{v} ) = \overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{v} - \overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{u} + \overrightarrow{v} \cdot \overrightarrow{v} - \overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{v} = \Vert \overrightarrow{u} \Vert^2 - \Vert \overrightarrow{v} \Vert^2
$$

Since $\Vert \overrightarrow{u} \Vert = \Vert \overrightarrow{v} \Vert$ we know that $(\overrightarrow{u} + \overrightarrow{v} ) \cdot (\overrightarrow{u} - \overrightarrow{v} ) = 0$.

Therefore the angle bisectors are perpendicular.

Is that the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful since $\vec{u}+\vec{v}$ lies on the angle bisector of $\vec{u},\vec{v}$ only if $\|u\|=\|v\|$.
That said, your proof is fine.

Comment: yes definitely, got ya. Thanks!